# Alter pandas DF using another location pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an original pandas df:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

original_to_insert = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [10, 10, 10],
                               'col2': [10, 10, 10],
                               'col3': [10, 10, 10]})
```

I would like to change it only at a single column, the specific single column should be changes using another pandas df:

```
df_true_false_dummies = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 0, 1],
                                      'col2': [0, 1, 0],
                                      'col3': [0, 0, 0]})
```

I have specific values i want to change per row + penalty:

```
value_to_add = np.array([5, 4, 2])

penalty = 0.95
```

so i would have the desired output (which column to change is decided by the `df_true_false_dummies` df:

```
desired_df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [10 + 5 * penalty, 10, 10 + 2 * penalty],
                           'col2': [10, 10 + 4 * penalty, 10],
                           'col3': [10, 10, 10]})
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In what way should the `value_to_add ` array be added to the data frame: left to right based on the index or top to bottom based on the column? In other words, if column 2 index 0 was True and not False how would you distribute the values from `value_to_add`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can multiple `value_to_add` with `df_true_false_dummies` by broadcasting, multiple `penalty` and last add original values in `original_to_insert`:

*Notice - index and columns has to be same in both DataFrames. Also length of `value_to_add` has to be same like length of each DataFrame.*

```
df = df_true_false_dummies * value_to_add[:, None] * penalty + original_to_insert
print (df)
    col1  col2  col3
0  14.75  10.0  10.0
1  10.00  13.8  10.0
2  11.90  10.0  10.0
```